# Refer to or INNER JOIN a Pandas dataframe value in the WHERE clause of a SQL Server query

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, join

I have a pandas dataframe from which I want to retrieve patient values from a SQL Server table based upon their matching patient id column called PatID

```
query = "SELECT * FROM [Hospital].[dbo].[Patient] WHERE PatID= df.PatID"

df2 = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)
```

Is there any way to join these matching ID values between my dataframe and SQL table or list within the SQL WHERE clause?

I am getting the multi part identifier error below
`The multi-part identifier "df.PatID" could not be bound`

Answer (score 1):

I think that generates a list of your ids and concatenate it in your sql query is  the easiest way to solve this problem

```
ids = ','.join(df['PatID'].unique())
query = f"SELECT * FROM [Hospital].[dbo].[Patient] WHERE PatID in ({ids})"
df2 = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)
```

Be careful with this solution. You will load all the ids from your DF to memory (if you are working with a large dataframe you will have trouble)

If your dataframe doesn't fit in memory, I guess that you will need to transfer data from df to sql-server and after join it, or from sql-server to python and after merge it.

Comment: Thanks I will try it, my dataframe came from a text file of 820K rows and the file size is 107 MB